# I have a question regarding the complex sentence

Tags: grammar, types-of-sentences

Sentence: "We investigated the acceptability and comprehensibility of both native-Thai and native-English instructors (ten of each), as these subjects listen to controlled passages produced by 4 Thai-English bilingual speakers and another 4 native-Thai speakers".

Is it okay to put a comma after the main clause in a complex sentence like the sentence above?
As far as I know, when a dependent clause appears before the main clause, a comma is used after the dependent clause.

Comment: I don't follow you, The 'main' clause in your example is the whole sentence. The "as" expression is a preposition phrase, not a clause.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be OK? If I was reading the sentence aloud I would certainly need to pause for breath in the middle.